# Majority element array Java O(nlogn)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The majority element in an array of size n is an element that appears more than n/2 times. I have to write a function that returns the majority element(if there is one, else return -1) and it must be O(nlogn). This is what I got:

```
public class MyMajority implements Majority {
    public int findMajority(Sequence numbers) {
      if (numbers.size()==0) { 
            return -1;
        }
        
        return major(numbers,0,numbers.size()-1);
    }
    
    public int major(Sequence numbers, int low, int high) {
 
        if (low == high){
          return numbers.get(low);  
        } 
        
        int mid = (high - low) / 2 + low;
        int left_major = major(numbers, low, mid);
        int right_major = major(numbers, mid + 1, high);
        
        if (left_major == right_major){
           return left_major; 
        } 
   
        int left_count = getFrequency(numbers, left_major);
        int right_count = getFrequency(numbers, right_major);
  
        return left_count > numbers.size() / 2 ? left_major :
                (right_count > numbers.size() / 2 ? right_major : -1);
    }
    
    public int getFrequency(Sequence numbers, int major) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
            if(numbers.get(i)==major){
                count++;
                if(count> numbers.size()/2){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

However if I run the code some testcases say your algorithm is too slow.
But I'm pretty sure this is O(nlogn) am I missing something? Because I use divide and conquer and loop over the array so T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)=O(nlogn)

Comment: Use [Bayer Moore algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-majority-voting-algorithm/) that does it in O(n) worst case.

Comment: This is specifically an exercise on divide and conquer so I dont have a choice it must be O(nlogn)

Comment: To get the log(n) part you need to split the problem in half, solve each half and combine the results. Decreasing the list length by one gives n not log(n)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this approach, which should be `O(nlogn)`:

It's just simple `sort` and find the majority item.  Since the requirement indicated there is `always` a majority number, so here it did not consider the edge case.

```
public class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        int len = nums.length;
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        return nums[len/2];
    }
}
```